# converting IPv6 string to bytes + python

Tags: python

Just as we use `socket.inet_aton()` for converting Ipv4 string is there any way to convert the IPv6 address string in Windows.

The function `socket.inet_pton()` is only available for Unix.

So is there any other way for me to do that on windows and python 2.6 ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IPy](http://c0re.23.nu/c0de/IPy/) can do all sorts of IP address manipulations.

Also, `inet_pton()` is available as of [Windows Vista](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc805844%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but Python targets older releases as well.

Comment: I am using Windows7 and I tried to use inet_pton in python 2.6 but it raised an Atrribute Error so is there any workaround without installing new library ?

Comment: You could try using `ctypes` to bind to the relevant function in ws2_32.dll.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how to do what you have written ... Could you give me an example or perhaps links to what I should do ? Thanks a lot...

Comment: Yup am reading it and I have loaded the dll using ctypes.... then i wrote 'a = ctypes.WinDLL("ws2_32.dll")    import socket a.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET6,"122.122.122.122.122.122")' and I get 4 bytes parameter less.... Could you tell what am i missing here?

Comment: The third argument to the function.

Comment: But inet_pton has only 2 parameters - inet_pton( address_family, ip_string) ... Does the parameter of the dll change ?

Comment: Even in *nix the function has 3 parameters; when using a native function you must read the native documentation on that function.

Comment: But in Python document only 2 are given so I read that - 'http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html'... Thanks